# how can I pass the result in a shell script to a variable in Job

Tags: pentaho

Now I have a pentaho job using shell script to process some data.
But I found if I want to use the result in the script, I had to write that into a file and read the file to asign variables.
Is there an esaier way to use the result of a script step in the following steps?

This is the Script content.

[image: Script]

Here is the whole process.

[image: Job process]

Comment: #1 Could you share us a screen of your ktr and the shell step config? Variables in pentaho are complicated. #2 Are you using kjb or just ktr?

Comment: @JRichardsz I'm using kjb.  I will post some images.

Answer (score 0):

In pentaho you cannot create a variable and used in the same place.

Basically you just need to create one ktr and one job:

- the first one is in charge of perform some task and save the variable with **set-variable step** (**root job level option**)
- variables created in the first ktr are also available at job level

If you want to use the variable in another ktr

- the second ktr, at the beginning should use the **get-variable step** to retrieve the variable created in previous transformation
- transformations should be executed sequentially using a job

In your case, you should run the shell in the first ktr, transform the result into a variable and save it using set-variable. Your job which invokes the ktr, are able to use the variable create in the **previous** ktr

Comment: Now my process is like: start -> powershell script(write the result to a file) -> Set Variable step(Generate variable from the file above) -> Print it.  And this process works fine. So I think if the SetVariable  step can gengerate variable from file, is there any way to generate it directly.

Comment: Besides, I only see shell script step in kjb, but not in ktr. Is that brcause of the version? I am using 7.0.